# bind_result( ) not getting all results

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason it executes the statement and then the binds all values, but not the last value of `$postContent`.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['postID']))
    {
        $postID = $_GET['postID'];
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE postID = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $postID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($postID, $postTitle, $postCat, $postUser, $postDateTime, $postContent);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo $postContent;
        ?>
        <h1><?php echo $postTitle;?></h1>
    </div> <!-- End of box div -->
    <div class="blogroll"> <!-- Start of blogroll div -->
    <div class="top"></div> <!-- Start and end of top div -->

    <div class="post"> <!-- Start of post div -->
        <div class="post_date">Posted by <?php echo $postUser;?> on <?php echo $postDateTime ?> Category : <?php echo $postCat;?></div> <!-- Start and end of post_date div -->
        <div class="post_text"> <!-- Start of post_text div -->
            <?php echo $postContent;?>
        </div> <!-- End of post_text div -->
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your source table in the database is actually supplying a column for `$postContent` when you do `SELECT *`:

View the HTML source that is output by your PHP script, to see if the `$postContent` is actually appearing in the source but not onscreen. You have not escaped your database output for HTML (encoding `<` as `&lt;`, etc...), so it is possible that something in `$postContent` or an earlier variable is breaking your output.  Instead of directly echoing out those variables, wrap each one in `htmlspecialchars()` when printing them inside HTML.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($postTitle); ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($postUser); ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($postDateTime); ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($postCat); ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($postContent); ?>
```

Comment: The database does supply the column for postContent and it is in the same order as the bind_results show. I have tried what you suggest and no it doesn't show the postContent in the source code of the HTML page. Also the htmlspcialchars() didn't work either but as I plan to have HTML tags eg </br> I will continue to use it. You are being a great help

Comment: @user1136076 The only other thing I can suggest is to `var_dump($postContent)` and _all_ of the other variables to be certain they each contain what is expected

Comment: It seems that $postContent isnt getting any value. When I perform the SQL statement in phpMyadmin it does return one record with 6 columns, the last being postContent with type LongText.

Comment: I have changed the data type to Text and it now shows on the page. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1136076 That's interesting, I've never encountered that before.

Comment: I wouldn't of thought that would of been a problem but it was the only thing I could think of.

Comment: I have asked another question and wonder if you could again shed light as to the fix. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856961/how-to-call-a-php-class-method-from-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 2):

MySQLi is failing to allocate enough memory for the maximum size of a LONGTEXT object (~4Gb).

This is a known bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386.

The workaround is to convert LONGTEXT columns to MEDIUMTEXT or something else smaller, or consider using an alternative database or interface class.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is the hardest problem in the world to Google.